# facebook graphapi multiple image sharing and location action

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

This is the sample code on facebook site..its working fine.

```
 NSDictionary *properties = @{
                                     @"og:type": @"books.book",
                                     @"og:title": @"SmartFission",
                                     @"og:description": @"This is smartfission",
                                     // @"books:isbn": @"0-553-57340-3",
                                     };

        FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

        // Create an action
        FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
        action.actionType = @"books.reads";
        [action setObject:object forKey:@"books:book"];

        // Add the photo to the action. Actions
        // can take an array of images.
        [action setArray:arrPhoto forKey:@"image"];

        // Create the content
        FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
        content.action = action;
        content.previewPropertyName = @"books:book";       
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                         withContent:content
                                            delegate:self];
```

What i want is to share images and current location which i visited..i tried following..

```
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                                     @"og:type": @"place",
                                     @"og:title": @"SmartFission",
                                     @"og:description": @"This is smartfission",
                                      @"place:location:latitude": @"37.484828",
                      @"place:location:longitude": @"-122.148283"
                                     };

        FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

        // Create an action
        FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
        action.actionType = @"restaurant.visited";
        [action setObject:object forKey:@"place"];

        // Add the photo to the action. Actions
        // can take an array of images.
        [action setArray:arrPhoto forKey:@"image"];

        // Create the content
        FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
        content.action = action;
        content.previewPropertyName = @"place";       
    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                         withContent:content
                                            delegate:self];
```

I get the following **error:**

> Error Domain=com.facebook.Facebook.platform Code=102 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={error_reason=The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (FBAPIErrorDomain error 1611072.), error_description=An error occurred
>   during publishing., app_id=967614566643689, error_code=102}

I tried using other Actions and Object and they also give error.Only the sample code runs. Any kind of help will be apreciated. thanx

Comment: Are you getting this error for the first example, the second, or both?

Comment: for the sample code it runs fine..but for my code it gives error at first time

Comment: Are you sure you have all the required properties for a place? I haven't used them before but I've had a similar issue when not including all the properties for an object before.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/